# How to find the Quantified transformed coefficients in encoder x264 and in decoder libavcodec?

Tags: c, h.264, libavcodec, x264

I'm a student in computer science and I am working on h264 encoder and decoder.

I decided to use x264 and libavcodec and I downloaded code of these open libraries. Then, I searched for a month on how to do it. I think the quantified transformed coefficients are in `h->dct.luma8x8` and `h->dct.luma4x4` but they are no `luma16x16` so I'm disappointed.

Now, I suppose that Intra 16x16 macroblock have their coefficients in luma4x4 or luma8x8 but I'm not sure. Is there someone who knows about it and could give answers?

Furthermore, I have to find the same coefficients in decoder and I thought that they are in `sl->mb` but the coefficients in `sl->mb` are strange (there are a lot of 0s and values > 100 contrary to the encoder where values are close to 1-10..) I'm lost so I hope that someone have some advice to help me to continue my project.

EDIT :

I think the coefficients when the macroblock is encoded in `16x16IntraPrediction`  are in `luma4x4`. I always need help to understand how the decoder works.

EDIT :

I think the coefficients which are in `sl->mb` are always dequantized, maybe there is a variable who have the correct coefficient in `decode_cabac_residual_internal` but I didn't find it..

Comment: I'd saying asking on an h264 specific IRC channel may yield better answers than asking on here.

Comment: Thank you for your advice Aidan, I send a mail at ffmpeg but I have no answer so I try here too.